# ¿Son "abecedario" y "alfabeto" palabras completamente sinónimas?

Tags: sinónimos, sustantivos, alfabeto

El diccionario de la RAE define:

> **[abecedario](http://dle.rae.es/?id=046Dm60)**
>
> Del lat. tardío *abecedarium*.
>
> 1. m. Serie ordenada de las letras de un idioma.
> 2. m. Cartel o libro con las letras del abecedario, que sirve para enseñar a leer.
> 3. m. Orden alfabético.
> 4. m. Lista en orden alfabético.
> 5. m. abecé (‖ rudimentos de una ciencia).
> 6. m. Impr. Orden de las signaturas de los pliegos de una impresión cuando van señalados con letras.

Y por otro lado define:

> **[alfabeto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1jcYwTh)**
>
> Del lat. tardío *alphabētum*, y este del gr. ἀλφάβητος *alphábētos*,
>   formado sobre ἄλφα *álpha* 'alfa' y βῆτα *bêta* 'beta1', nombre de las dos
>   primeras letras griegas.
>
> 1. m. abecedario.
> 2. m. Conjunto de los símbolos empleados en determinados sistemas de comunicación.

Es decir, que *alfabeto* contiene todas las acepciones de *abecedario*, más una extra referente a los símbolos de los sistemas de comunicación. Esta última acepción sería la que haría que se dijera *alfabeto morse* en vez de *abecedario morse*. Sin embargo, en el CREA se puede encontrar al menos [una ocurrencia](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=0&texto=abecedario%20morse&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) de esta última, lo que me hace pensar que las palabras son completamente intercambiables.

Así pues, ¿son *abecedario* y *alfabeto* palabras completamente sinónimas? ¿O existe alguna situación en la que una no se pueda intercambiar por la otra?

Bonus: ¿cuál es la palabra que prefiere la RAE? ¿Se diría *alfabeto español*, *abecedario español*, o depende de la región?

Comment: Hay toda una serie de idiomas (por ejemplo: chino, griego, árabe) para los que no creo que se pueda utilizar **"abecedario"**, peo si **"alfabeto"**. En esos casos no serían intercambiables.

Comment: @user en los cuatro años que estuve aprendiendo japonés no usamos nunca ni "alfabeto" ni "abecedario", sino "silabario" y, como mucho, "lista de kanjis".

Comment: No se el caso concreto del japonés, pero por ejemplo: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul "El **alfabeto coreano** o hangul..." o https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfabeto_%C3%A1rabe "El **alfabeto árabe**, también conocido como «alifato» en español (de alif, su primera letra),1 es la escritura usada en muchas lenguas de Asia y África, tales como el árabe, el persa y el urdu." - no creo que en esos casos se pueda hablar de "**abecedario coreano**" o "**abecedario árabe**"

Comment: @user entiendo tu razonamiento, pero me preguntaba si eso no será porque la palabra "alfabeto" se usa más en esos casos. Si buscas "[abecedario coreano](https://www.google.es/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22abecedario+coreano%22)" o "[abecedario árabe](https://www.google.es/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22abecedario+%C3%A1rabe%22)" en Google sin ir más lejos, hay páginas que emplean esos términos, y no creo que sea incorrecto.

Comment: Efectivamente, si se utilizan es que debe ser correcto. Y si buscas "**abecedario japonés**"  o "**alfabeto japonés**" en Google también hay miles de resultados, luego también debe ser correcto.

Answer (score 4):

Tal como indicas:
- `abecedario` es un alfabeto solo relativo a las letras latinas.
- `abecedario morse` sería correcto si los símbolos morse tienen una correspondencia directa con letras latinas.
- `abecedario árabe` sería un uso incorrecto, ya que no hay correspondencia directa con las letras latinas.
- En un término genérico se podría decir que el abecedario es un alfabeto de letras latinas.

Comment: Pero como se dice: "Si buscas "abecedario coreano" o "**abecedario árabe**" en Google sin ir más lejos, hay páginas que emplean esos términos, y no creo que sea incorrecto. "

Comment: Alfabeto árabe sería lo correcto.

Comment: Según tu mismo argumento, "alfabeto árabe" sería un uso incorrecto ya que no hay una correspondencia directa con las letras griegas ...

Comment: No es mi argumento. Alfabeto es un conjunto ordenado de letras o símbolos de escritura. No se refiere solamente al alfabeto griego. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que depende de lo que busques.

Si buscas lo "correcto", pues sería ceñirse a la definición de la RAE, y como has dicho, la palabras son totalmente intercambiables excepto para definir símbolos de otros sistemas de comunicación (entiendo que se refiere a aquellos sistemas de comunicación que no sean estrictamente lenguajes hablados y/o escritos, como por ejemplo los símbolos de un pentagrama o el morse), aún cuando alguien la haya usado de otra manera ocasionalmente.
En el resto de casos, sea cual sea el lenguaje y su procedencia, las dos palabras serían intercambiables.

Si buscas lo que se usa, desde luego yo no usaría *abecedario* para definir los símbolos del japonés, coreano, chino, árabe, el *alfabeto* cirílico, jeroglíficos egipcios, cuneiforme, etc.
Todos ellos por una razón muy básica: no tienen ni a, ni be, ni ce. Parece un juego de palabras tonto y es un razonamiento muy simplón, pero es que lo dice la misma palabra y, ahondando un poco, tiene mucho que ver con lo que apunta Veilkrand de la herencia latina.

Si bien es cierto que tampoco usaría alfabeto para referirme a los *kanjis* japoneses, creo que sonaría mucho mejor que usar abecedario. Y para otros lenguajes no basados en el alfabeto latino y otros sistemas de comunicación, pues yo creo que a cada uno el uso y costumbre les ha dado su propio nombre.
 Volviendo al pentagrama como ejemplo, yo he oído y leído la expresión "alfabeto musical", pero casi siempre sin referirse a las notas como símbolos sino a las herramientas armónicas y melódicas que se usan en una pieza musical (escalas, cadencias, algo así como referirse al estilo narrativo en vez de a las propias letras), y aún así, está muy lejos de ser de uso común, mientras que, por ejemplo, "las notas musicales" se oye y lee continuamente. Lo mismo ocurre con muchos otros, en los que alfabeto es una palabra que, simplemente, no se usa (o por lo menos yo la he escuchado poco).
Supongo que la herencia latina, o el uso reiterado de ambas palabras para referirse a un lenguaje per sé, ha ganado la partida.